# What's gonna happen when all IPv4 changes to IPv6?

Tags: network, ip

I was guessing what could happen when all IPv4 be changed to IPv6 , like pen-testing tools and network configuration for common users.

Will all the IPv4 be automatically translated to a IPv6 new one ? Or the user need to manually input the new version ? Won't this be a big trouble somewhere? What about tools that are all based on IPv4?Scripts?Programs?

I'm looking for a broad answer with a logic to follow , don't need a deep answer.

Comment: It is highly unlikely that all IPv4 will be changed over to IPv6 at any time in the next decade or two, or three, or four.

Comment: How is this question related to information security?

Comment: Because of SPAM, and blacklists required for email to function, SMTP will likely always be dominantly IPv4.  Source- private MAAWG meetings.

Comment: _The end_, my friend. _The end_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Philip pointed out, the question is not directly related to security. However, there are a lot of security implications associated with both deployment and transition to IPv6 . Many researchers in the past have studied these implications and have proposed effective solutions to the problems and the research is still ongoing.

The paper ["IPv6 Security Challenges" (by Caicedo and others)](http://www.researchgate.net/publication/224384582_IPv6_Security_Challenges/file/79e4150a768111a857.pdf) gives a brief overview about these implications. There are many research paper discussing this issue in more details. I would recommend you to read those papers in case you want to learn more about this transition.